# Modify an ElementCriteriaModel to compare against numeric field

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

Can anyone tell me why this is returning all entries instead of entries with a `creditsUsed` field > 0? `creditsUsed` is a number field that I created for this entry type.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->authorId = craft()->userSession->getUser()->id;
$criteria->section = 'news';
$criteria->creditsUsed > 0;
$criteria->status = null;
$entries = $criteria->total();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what's actually happening with this line of code...

```
$criteria->creditsUsed > 0;
```

You are actually generating the **boolean** value of "is creditsUsed more than zero". Granted, you aren't setting it to an actual variable, but nonetheless you are generating a boolean value. For example:

```
$moreThanZeroCreditsUsed = ($criteria->creditsUsed > 0);
```

Even though you're not assigning that new boolean value to a variable, it's still valid PHP (and therefore no error is thrown).

What it looks like you are trying to do instead is to actually set the value of `creditsUsed`, which you'd need to use an **equals sign** to do:

```
$criteria->creditsUsed = "whatever";
```

If my memory serves me correctly, the way to denote a comparison on an ElementCriteriaModel is to simply pass the comparison as a string:

```
$criteria->creditsUsed = "> 0";
```

See the last example in [this subsection...](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax) Granted, it's being applied via Twig syntax, but it's still modifying the ElementCriteriaModel in the same way:

```
craft.entries.width('>= 100')
```